# How to place a Datagrid at a specific location inside another datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid DG1 which has a column called Signal and there is another datagrid DG2 which has list of new signals.

So whenever I click on the cell of signal column of a row I have to place the DG2 right below the cell and when I change the row to next row Signal column cell again it should open a datagrid right below that.

```
    private void DG1_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Signal")
        {
            // Gets the selected datagrid row.
            DataGridRow row = e.Row;
            Signal signalItem = (Signal)row.Item;
            // Get the cell content
            DataGridCell cell = GetDataGridCellContent(DG1_PreparingCellForEdit, row, "Signal");

            AvailableSglDG.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;                

            DG2.Height = 300;
            DG2.Width = 690;

            Point position = cell.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d));
            controlPosition = this.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d));
            position.X -= controlPosition.X;
            position.Y -= controlPosition.Y;

            DG2.Margin = new Thickness(position.X, position.Y, 0,0);
        }
    }[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt1Z7.png)
```

it should be like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq13d.png)